# Get latest appointments from outlook with powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook

I want to get the appointments for today and tomorrow of 3 different persons that are on my address book. These persons have the calendar shared on outlook.

How can I get this info with powershell? I don't mind getting the data from a local outlook instance but would prefer something connected directly to the server.

Comment: did you tried with `ComObject Outlook.Application` ?

Answer (score 6):

You can start with this (local outlook instance), you may need to further filter the result based on some properties to find your friends information:

```
$olFolderCalendar = 9
$ol = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$ns = $ol.GetNamespace('MAPI')
$Start = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString()
$End = (Get-Date).ToShortDateString()

$Filter = "[MessageClass]='IPM.Appointment' AND [Start] > '$Start' AND [End] < '$End'"
$ns.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderCalendar).Items.Restrict($Filter)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's Exchange 2007 or better you have to option of using the Exchange Web Services Managed API with Powershell.  The API is here:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13480

Glen Scales has some excellent examples of using it with Powershell on his blog:

http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2009/11/basic-powershell-script-to-show.html

Answer (score -2):

Looking at whole function/script from [Scripting Guy](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/05/24/use-powershell-to-export-outlook-calendar-information/), this seems a useful.
Here an example output:

```
Subject  Start                                   Duration Location
-------   -----                                  -------- --------
Emea IT support team x64 b... 16-9-2016 14:30:00 - 30 -
Citrix receiver in the NL ... 13-9-2016 12:30:00 - 30 - Webex
Workstations OS Patching  ... 12-9-2016 12:30:00 - 30 - INPNQ-Conference Room
Remedy Demo & Training Ses... 13-9-2016 09:30:00 - 120 - webex
```

It does require to have Outlook running.

Comment: This answer should have included the important parts of the linked page.

Comment: @derekbaker783: I refer to the function(=script=code) on that page. If that is unclear then you do not understand that code.

Comment: ["Links are fantastic, but they should never be the only piece of information in your answer."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259)